# Speeding up row counting in MySQL

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, count

Suppose, for illustrative purposes, you are running a library using a simple MySQL "books" table with three columns:

(id, title, status)

- **id** is the primary key
- **title** is the title of the book
- **status** could be an enum describing the book's current state (e.g. AVAILABLE, CHECKEDOUT, PROCESSING, MISSING)

A simple query to report how many books fall into each state is:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*) FROM books GROUP BY status
```

or to specifically find how many books are available:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books WHERE status = "AVAILABLE"
```

However, once the table grows to millions of rows, these queries take several seconds to complete. Adding an index to the "status" column doesn't appear to make a difference in my experience.

Aside from periodically caching the results or explicitly updating summary info in a separate table each time a book changes state (via triggers or some other mechanism), are there any techniques for speeding up these kinds of queries? It seems that the COUNT queries end up looking at every row, and (without knowing more details) I'm a bit surprised that this information can't somehow be determined from the index.

**UPDATE**

Using the sample table (with an indexed "status" column) with 2 million rows, I benchmarked the GROUP BY query. Using the InnoDB storage engine, the query takes 3.0 - 3.2 seconds on my machine. Using MyISAM, the query takes 0.9 - 1.1 seconds.  There was no significant difference between count(*), count(status), or count(1) in either case.

MyISAM is admittedly a bit faster, but I was curious to see if there was a way to make an equivalent query run *much* faster (e.g. 10-50 ms -- fast enough to be called on every webpage request for a low-traffic site) without the mental overhead of caching and triggers. It sounds like the answer is "there's no way to run the direct query quickly" which is what I expected - I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing an easy alternative.

Comment: Does it make a difference when you use: select count(indexed_column) from book?

Comment: are you using innodb or myisam?

Comment: @Boekwurm: It does not :) . mysql optimizes the query so count(indexed_column), count(*) and count(1) return with the same level of efficiency.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

So the question is

> are there any techniques for speeding up these kinds of queries?

Well, not really. A column-based storage engine would probably be faster with those SELECT COUNT(*) queries but it would be less performant for pretty much any other query.

Your best bet is to maintain a summary table via triggers. It doesn't have much overhead and the SELECT part will be instantaneous no matter how big the table. Here's some boilerplate code:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER ai_books AFTER INSERT ON books
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE books_cnt SET total = total + 1 WHERE status = NEW.status
//
CREATE TRIGGER ad_books AFTER DELETE ON books
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE books_cnt SET total = total - 1 WHERE status = OLD.status;
//
CREATE TRIGGER au_books AFTER UPDATE ON books
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (OLD.status <> NEW.status)
    THEN
        UPDATE books_cnt SET total = total + IF(status = NEW.status, 1, -1) WHERE status IN (OLD.status, NEW.status);
    END IF;
END
//
```

Comment: A question, how about views instead of triggers ? Would a view be any faster than running the query on the original table ?

Comment: No, until MySQL implements materialized views their performance will be about the same as the corresponding SELECT statement.

Comment: But does this not fly in the face of internal SQL logic? Doesn't MySQL keep a row ESTIMATE because it is IMPOSSIBLE to keep a row exact count without significant performance issues?

For Example, you have cell or row level locking in many instances. Meaning you can insert/delete two rows at the same time, but not if you implement this since everything is tied to a single piece of data, that can only be edited one at a time.

Comment: Is it possible to use this for a case where I want to use a WHERE clause to get the count? Like get the column count only for a specific author?

Answer (score 10):

from: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html

> InnoDB does not keep an internal count
>   of rows in a table. (In practice, this
>   would be somewhat complicated due to
>   multi-versioning.) To process a SELECT
>   COUNT(*) FROM t statement, InnoDB must
>   scan an index of the table, which
>   takes some time if the index is not
>   entirely in the buffer pool.

The solution suggested is:

> To get a fast count, you have to use a
>   counter table you create yourself and
>   let your application update it
>   according to the inserts and deletes
>   it does. SHOW TABLE STATUS also can be
>   used if an approximate row count is
>   sufficient.

In short: count(*) (on innoDB) will take a long time time for tables containing a large number of rows. This is by design and can't be helped.

Write your own workaround.

Comment: The passage you have cited does NOT apply to the case at hand. MyISAM only optimizes COUNT(*) with no WHERE clause, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 10):

MyISAM is actually pretty fast with count(*) the downside is that the MyISAM storage is not that reliable and best avoided where data integrity is critical.

InnoDB can be very slow to perform count(*) type queries, cause it is designed to allow for multiple concurrent views of the same data. So at any point in time, its not enough to go to the index to get the count.

From: http://www.mail-archive.com/mysql@lists.mysql.com/msg120320.html

> The database starts with 1000 records
>   in it I start a transaction You start
>   a transaction I delete 50 records You
>   add 50 records I do a COUNT(*) and see
>   950 records. You do a COUNT(*) and see
>   1050 records.  I commit my transaction
>   - database now has 950 records to everyone but  you. You commit your
>   transaction - database has 1000
>   records again.
>
> How InnoDB keeps up with which records
>   are "visible" or "modifiable" with 
>   respect to any transaction is through
>   row-level locking, transaction 
>   isolation levels, and
>   multi-versioning.
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/innodb-transaction-model.html
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/innodb-multi-versioning.html
>
> That is what makes counting how many
>   records each person can see is not so 
>   straight-forward.

So bottom line is you will need to look at caching the counts somehow as opposed to going to the table if you need to get at this information frequently and fast.

Comment: MyISAM's `COUNT` is fast _only_ without a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 6):

> There was no significant difference between count(*), count(status), or count(1)

count(column) returns the number of lines where column is NOT NULL. Since 1 is NOT NULL, and status is also, presumably, NOT NULL, the database will optimize away the test and convert them all to count(*). Which, ironically, does not mean "count lines where all columns are not null" (or any other combination), it just means "count lines"...

Now, back to your question, you can't have your cake and eat it...

- If you want an "exact" count to be available at all times, then you have to increment and decrement in real time, via triggers, which slows down your writes
- Or you can use count(*), but this will be slow
- Or you can settle for a rough estimate, or an out-of-date value, and use caching or other probabilistic approaches.

Generally, on values above about "a few", NO-ONE is interested in an exact real-time count. It is a red herring anyway, as by the time you read it, the value will most likely have changed.

Answer (score 4):

Many answers here said an index wouldn't help but in my case it did...

My table used MyISAM, and had only about 100k rows. The query:

```
select count(*) from mytable where foreign_key_id=n
```

took 7-8 seconds to complete.

I added an index on the `foreign_key_id`:

```
create index myindex on mytable (foreign_key_id) using btree;
```

After creating the index, the select statement above reported an execution time of 0.00 seconds.

Comment: Your second query probably hit the query cache, returning the last result instantly regardless of indexing.

Comment: Good point - I just tried my query again (several days later, and the contents of the table have been modified) and the count took 0.02 seconds. So you're probably right about the cache, but it still seems as though the index helped significantly.

Comment: add sql_no_cache after select for avoiding caching

Comment: 0.02s may mean that there are very few rows.  `COUNT(*)`, in the absence of caching, takes time proportional to the resulting count.