# How do I calculate the last page?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, pagination

```
    $results = $qb->add('select', 'p')
        ->add('from', 'GabrielUploadBundle:Post p')
        ->add('where', 'p.upvotes >'.$minVotes)
        ->add('orderBy', 'p.createdAt DESC')
        ->where('p.type = :type')
        ->setParameter('type', $contentType)
        ->setMaxResults($pageSize)
        ->setFirstResult($pageSize * ($pageNumber - 1))
        ->getQuery();
```

url/posts/rating?pageNumber=1&pageSize=2

works 100%, but I need to find a way to find out what the last page is so I can set the "next" button as disabled.

Comment: just get the total number of rows, divided by limit, and then get the ceiling value. thats the last page

Comment: if that's mysql, then do a `select sql_calc_found_rows ...`, so you can then do a `select found_rows()`. This saves you having to do a separate query to get the total row count.

Comment: If you only need a "next page" link, then look at my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16348093/1948627