# How to count number of rows which is related to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have two tables:

#### CATEGORY

```
category_id         int(10)          UNSIGNED  AUTO_INCREMENT
category_title      varchar(255)
```

#### PRODUCT

```
product_id          int(10)          UNSIGNED  AUTO_INCREMENT
product_category    int(10)          UNSIGNED 
product_title       varchar(255)
```

---

Column `product_category` is a foreign key related to `category_id`. Here is some data:

```
category_id    category_title
-----------    --------------
          3    Cellphone
          4    Motherboard
          5    Monitor

product_id    product_category    product_title
----------    ----------------    -------------
         3    3                   Samsung Galaxy SIII
         4    3                   Apple iPhone 5
         5    3                   HTC One X
```

How I can fetch all categories with the count of products?

```
category_id    category_title    products_count
-----------    --------------    --------------
          3    Cellphone         3
          4    Motherboard       9
          5    Monitor           7
```

I used this query:

```
SELECT 
    `category_id` AS  `id`,
    `category_title` AS  `title`,
    COUNT(  `product_id` ) AS  `count` 

FROM  `ws_shop_category` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  `ws_shop_product`
        ON  `product_category` =  `category_id` 

GROUP BY  `category_id` 
ORDER BY  `title` ASC
```

But it takes too long: **( 254 total, Query took 4.4019 sec)**.
How can I make this query better?

---

#### DESC

Adding `DESC` before the query, give me this result:

```
id  select_type table               type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      ws_shop_category    ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL    255     Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      ws_shop_product     ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL    14320
```

---

#### SHOW CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `ws_shop_product` (
 `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `product_category` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `product_title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=14499 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE `ws_shop_category` (
 `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `category_title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=260 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Why you are using LEFT OUTER JOIN and not INNER JOIN? that would obviously slows down the query. not to mentioned it would count even those who have no match.

Comment: How have you defined the indexes on your tables? Slow queries often indicate that no index is used. You can see the query plan by adding `DESC ` at the start of the query and executing it.

Comment: @Edper Yes, inner join gave me a fast result, but I used left outer join for categories with no products (count = 0).

Comment: @ErikSchierboom I've added the result of `DESC` before my query.

Comment: @Edper the problem is the total lack of indexes, not of `LEFT JOIN`. If left join is needed, it should be used. With only 250 rows returned, it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @user2450111 Ah yes, that indicates that no indexes are used. I'll post and answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table does not define any indexes. It is easily remedied though, by adding the indexes using the following statememts:

```
ALTER TABLE `product` ADD INDEX `product_category` (`product_category`);
ALTER TABLE `category` ADD PRIMARY KEY(category_id);
```

Now if you run your query again, the `DESC` should show you that the query uses keys and should be much faster.

Comment: the `category` table is already have `category_id` as `primary key`. I add the first index, and my query, boom. Thanks a lot. One question: all foreign key need to be an index?

Comment: @user2450111 It would help if you added the `SHOW CREATE TABLE category;` output (and same for `product` table) in the question. Then we would know all constraints, indexes and engine used. Your EXPLAIN plan does not show any index defined in `category`.

Comment: @ypercube Thanks for your comment, I've added it to my post :)

Comment: @user2450111 Not all foreign keys need to be an index (unless you want to enforce the values to be valid), but it helps a great deal when joining.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ws_shop_category.*, count(ws_shop_product.product_category) as products_count        
from ws_shop_category
left join ws_shop_product
on (ws_shop_category.category_id = ws_shop_product.product_category)
group by
    ws_shop_category.category_id
order by  
    ws_shop_category.category_title asc
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do?

Comment: Show all categories, and count how many products exist in each category. Am I  missing something?

Comment: Now that you edited, it's the same as the OP's query. The problem is efficiency though, he already has the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you require high performance, I recommend storing number of products in a category as a column to product_category or in a separate table. You can update relevant counters on every product insert/delete (manually or using triggers) or you can use a scheduled job to update all the counters every N minutes.

You can find example of using triggers here: [Speeding up row counting in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332624/speeding-up-row-counting-in-mysql)