# Save select count() result in table and update every insert or select count every time it's needed

Tags: mysql

I have 4 table A, B, C and D (with 100.000-200.000 records).
All record count on that table will be used again and really often. Insert and count process often used, almost every 500-1000 milliseconds. Count process not a simple select count(*) from table, but it use where to pointing to data that need to be count.  I need 50-100 milis count process

Which one is faster?

Save select count() result in table and update its data every insert

or

Select count() when it's needed?

Comment: you need count after every 500-1000 milliseconds.so i think store one will bee fast.so that at the of fetch you need only column value .

Comment: save SELECT COUNT, suggest you can use a trigger at every insert and delete to update the count

Comment: Do you need a solution for both SQL Server and MySQL?

Comment: SQL OR MYSQL?which one are you using

Comment: possible duplicate of [Speeding up row counting in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332624/speeding-up-row-counting-in-mysql)