# Optimising MySQL count(*) query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a mysql query that needs to count the number of rows associated to each column. I was wondering if someone could help me optimise it as currently it's taking around 10 seconds to run and this is for my website. (not ideal)

The query is:

```
SELECT model_make, count(*) FROM deals group by model_make UNION ALL
SELECT model_brand, count(*) FROM deals group by model_brand UNION ALL
SELECT model_name, count(*) FROM deals group by model_name;
```

I'm sure there is a quicker way to do this? If this really is the only way to run this, what other options are there to speed this up?

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk: Thats a myth: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332624/speeding-up-row-counting-in-mysql

Comment: `COUNT(1)` will also work... But I don't think this would make any difference

Comment: share your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have an index on each of the columns you are grouping on. Still, MySQL must scan through the index.

Other solution would be to calculate the counts once and store them then update them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the count (like you express in your original question), you could do:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT model_make)) as CountModelMake, 
COUNT(DISTINCT model_brand)) as CountModelBrand, 
COUNT(DISTINCT model_name)) as CountModelName
FROM deals group by model_make
```

Hope it helps!