# What is a less expensive alternative to "mysqli_query(SELECT count(*) from table where created_at > $time"

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have a script that I need to run in under **1 second**. I have this line that takes **4.4 seconds** on average to execute.

```
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT count(*) from record where created_at > '$time'");
```

The rest of the script takes less than **0.1 second**.

Comment: Do you have any index on this table?

Comment: When selecting all your really can't without putting an index on your table. You could select only the columns you need ? (unless you literally need all of them).   Also look into using prepared statements because this isn't secure.

Comment: I wonder if `count(1)` would be faster than `count(*)`.  nevermind https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1 no difference

Comment: it could also depend how you're fetching/looping. There isn't enough information on the schema/columns/values and how this is used.

Comment: *"Also look into using prepared statements because this isn't secure"* - @clearshot66 - Only if there is user input, and that we don't know and as to the rest of what wasn't posted.

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) from record where created_at > NOW()`  and check if it's hitting any performance bottlenecks (e.g. no index on created date etc).

Comment: @DominiqueVienne When I run `SHOW INDEX FROM record\G` I see that the primary key, which is an auto-incrementing integer, is the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I aggree with @xQbert and wonder if COUNT(1) or COUNT(ID) could increase speed... but nevermind...

*Edit - just had the answer*
[Count(*) vs Count(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1?noredirect=1&lq=1)

You should add an index involving created_at row. Try to add a UNIQUE INDEX on created_at if possible or on created_at and another row (i.e. created_at + user_id). The more restrictive you will be, the faster you will get your results.

Another point is, if you only need 5 results... limit your query with LIMIT 0,5

Believe me... PHP won't be faster than MySQL! ;)

Comment: I found a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41368845/4128530 same as your suggestion

Comment: @PhillisPeters How fast is your query now?

Comment: 0.00021219253540039 secs

Comment: Wonderful news! ;)